# How to display values in a column in Excel based on a matching value in another column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vlookup

I have 2 sheets in Excel, one that contains three columns of data (`Name` `Date` `Time`), and another sheet that will contain one column (`Name`) and is currently empty. What I trying to figure out is how to display the names on Sheet 2 that match with the January 25th date.

### Sheet 1

```
Name    Date        Time
A      25-Jan       noon
B      19-Feb       6pm
C      25-Jan       3pm
```

### Sheet2 (result sheet)

```
    Name    
    A
    C
```

Comment: Check out a simple example----[Find data in other sheet](http://www.xlorate.com/vba-examples.html#Find Data in other Sheet)--http://www.xlorate.com/vba-examples.html#Find Data in other Sheet

Comment: Is there a way I can use an excel function to do this?

Comment: Use Index-Match, you tagged excel-vba though

Comment: okay cool, yea my fault

Answer (score 0):

supposing that your lookup date is in `B1` in `sheet2`,
try this formula in `A2`in `Sheet2`, then drag and copy down until you see all the matches:

```
=IF(ISERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$99,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$99=$B$1,ROW(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$99)),ROW(1:1)),1)),"",INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$99,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$99=$B$1,ROW(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$99)),ROW(1:1)),1))
```

**`$B$1`** is the cell that contains your lookup value, i.e. **`25-Jan`**.

**this is an array formula, so press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> to calculate the formula.**

the formula returns blank cells after all the matches are listed.